Python deployment for dashboarding
I am investigating dashboard possibilities, one of which is using Python combined with Plotly.
Say I develop a script which reads a database and visualizes its data, how can I best deploy it on a standalone (modern) PC?
One of my thoughts was conversion to .exe and let it run every so often. However I find the produced .exe quite slow compared to the original script.
Any suggestions on better practices?

I would look into this question, and maybe this post has some useful insights.

Do you have a Virtual Environment (any type, e.g. the default venv) activated for your Python code? This significantly reduces executable size if you have a lot of packages installed globally, simply run the builder in the same terminal where you activated your VirtualEnv.
Also, I've noticed that generally, executables with dynamically linked content (instead of everything being held inside the .exe. For example, in PyInstaller it's --onedir) take less time to load.
Python itself isn't quite fast when it comes to compiled executables, it needs to bundle the interpreter which then runs your code, which means that it doesn't run your code on the low level in normal conditions and has some overhead. Basically, it adds a few more steps that Python must complete to run you application.

Yes, it is already with the minimum required packages. I will look into --onedir, had not tried that!
